# Get the first date from the latest repeated group

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops

I'm trying to creare a SQL Server query (without LOOPING) for the following:

I need to get latest inserted [Price] and [PriceDate] from a table [Prices] but with the following condition> if the price "before the latest", and "the latest" are the same, return the "before the latest" until the previous price is not the same anymore.

Example:

| ID | AssetID | PriceDate | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 19969 | 8/31/2022 | 1.89 |
| 2 | 19969 | 7/31/2022 | 1.89 |
| 3 | 19969 | 6/30/2022 | 1.89 |
| 4 | 19969 | 5/31/2022 | 1.89 |
| 5 | 19969 | 4/30/2022 | 1 |
| 6 | 19969 | 3/31/2022 | 1 |
| 7 | 19969 | 2/28/2022 | 1 |
| 8 | 19969 | 1/31/2022 | 1 |
| 9 | 19969 | 1/3/2022 | 1.89 |
| 10 | 19969 | 12/31/2021 | 1.89 |

So for this example, **it should return ID 4, PriceDate 5/31/2022**. The latest entry is 8/31/2022, but since the price before (7/31/2022) is 1.89 I need to get this one, and since the one before (6/30/2022) is still 1.89, I need to keep looking back, until the previous entry (PriceDate) has a different price (4/30/2022).

Note that for 1/3/2022 the price is 1.89 again, however I don't care about this date since it belong to a different sequential group.

I would do it with a loop, but since this table has thousands of thousands of records for different AssetIDs, I didn't want to take this approach.

This what I got so far, but it not returning the right date by AssetID.

```
SELECT AssetID, price, PRICEDATE,
     FIRST_VALUE(PriceDate) OVER (
        PARTITION BY Price ORDER BY PriceDate 
        ) AS LastValue
FROM PricesSELECT AssetID, price, PRICEDATE,
     FIRST_VALUE(PriceDate) OVER (
        PARTITION BY Price ORDER BY PriceDate 
        ) AS LastValue
FROM Prices
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Please correct the conflicting tags. (I am talking about `mysql` and `sql-server`)

Comment: Ok, just fixed it.

Comment: Can you review the SQL statement you posted, and correct it ? (Somewhere half-way there is a `SELECT`...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return id 4 and 8, because those are the id's where a price change did occur.

```sql
select *
from (
   SELECT 
      id, 
      PriceDate, 
      price, 
      lead(price) over (order by id) previousprice
   from prices 
) x
where price<>previousprice
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/86LzBD4-)

output:

| id | PriceDate | price | previousprice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2022-05-31 | 1.89 | 1.00 |
| 8 | 2022-01-31 | 1.00 | 1.89 |

Comment: This was a great approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll want them separated by AssetID too.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #P;

CREATE TABLE #P
(ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
AssetID INT,
PriceDate DATE,
Price Money);

INSERT INTO #P
(
AssetID,
PriceDate,
Price)
VALUES
(
19969,
'2022-08-31',
1.89
),
(
19969,
'2022-07-31',
1.89
),
(
19969,
'2022-06-30',
1.89
),
(
19969,
'2022-05-31',
1.89
),
(
19969,
'2022-04-30',
1.0
),
(
19969,
'2022-03-31',
1.0
),
(
19969,
'2022-02-28',
1.0
),
(
19969,
'2022-01-31',
1.0
),
(
19969,
'2022-01-03',
1.89
),
(
19969,
'2021-12-31',
1.89
);

SELECT * FROM #P;

WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 
        ID,
        AssetID,
        PriceDate,
        Price,
        LEAD(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY AssetID ORDER BY AssetID, PriceDate DESC) AS PreviousPrice
    FROM
        #P
)
SELECT * FROM cte 
WHERE PreviousPrice <> Price OR PreviousPrice IS NULL
ORDER BY PriceDate DESC;
```

Comment: If you only need the top row, just add at SELECT TOP (1) * from cte...

Answer (score 0):

Other than @Luuk, you can also take these solutions:

```html
  select 
  AssetID
  ,max(pricedate) PriceDate
  from (
     SELECT 
      assetid, 
      PriceDate, 
      price, 
      lag(price) over (order by assetid,pricedate) previousprice
     from prices 
  ) x
  where price<>previousprice
  group by assetid
```

and this one

```html
select
                p.AssetID
                ,MIN(p.PriceDate) as Pricedate
                from Prices as p
                left join (
                            select
                            p.AssetID
                            ,MAX(p.PriceDate) as Pricedate
                            from Prices as p
                            left join (
                                        --get last price info per asset
                                        select 
                                        p.*
                                        from prices as p 
                                        --get last price date per asset
                                        inner join (
                                                     select
                                                     AssetID
                                                     ,max(pricedate) Pricedate
                                                     from Prices
                                                     where AssetID = 19969
                                                     group by AssetID
                                                   ) as pmax on pmax.AssetID = p.AssetID and pmax.Pricedate = p.PriceDate
                                        ) as pmax on pmax.AssetID = p.AssetID
                            where p.AssetID = 19969
                                and p.Price <> pmax.Price
                            group by p.AssetID
                          ) as pmin on pmin.AssetID = p.AssetID
                where p.AssetID = 19969
                    and p.PriceDate > pmin.Pricedate
                group by p.AssetID
```

Comment: When posting code (other code than HTML), you might better separate the code from the text using a triple back-quoot, instead of `<!-- language: lang-html -->`, or use the `{}` (see: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/724039 )  This is because `Run code snippet` has no function when you post SQL code.